# How do I make one trigger fire but ignore the actions done by another trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2016

I have 2 triggers I need to make. The problem is that when a user inserts/updates a row, Trigger 1 fires, which updates the 3 columns defined below, which causes Trigger 2 to fire. But Trigger 2 is also firing indepedently because of the user's original action. I can't merge these triggers into one because of other constraints, so how do I make it so that the user's action causes Trigger 2 to only fire on the user's action and NOT because of Trigger 1?

Trigger 1: any time the row is updated, update 3 specific columns called UpdateDate, UpdatedByHostName, and UpdatedByLogin. This will tell us who last changed the other columns in the row

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigUpdateStandardTableData_ProductionOrder] ON [dbo].[Production Order] AFTER UPDATE AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON 
UPDATE [dbo].[Production Order] SET UpdateDate = GETDATE(), UpdatedByHostName = HOST_NAME(), UpdatedByLogin = SUSER_NAME() 
FROM [dbo].[Production Order] INNER JOIN inserted ii ON [dbo].[Production Order].RowPointer = ii.RowPointer 
END
```

Trigger 2: when a row is inserted/updated/deleted, copy the affected rows into another table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

alter TRIGGER [dbo].[trigLogChanges_ProductionOrder] 
   ON  [dbo].[Production Order]
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN    
    set nocount on
    set xact_abort on

    declare @ChangeBatchID nvarchar(36) = newid()
    declare @ChangeType nvarchar(7) = 'UNKNOWN'
    declare @ChangeDateTime datetime2 = getdate()

    if exists(select top 1 1 from inserted) and exists(select top 1 1 from deleted)
    begin    
        set @ChangeType = 'UPDATE'    
    end

    if exists(select top 1 1 from inserted) and not exists(select top 1 1 from deleted)
    begin    
        set @ChangeType = 'INSERT'    
    end

    if not exists(select top 1 1 from inserted) and exists(select top 1 1 from deleted)
    begin    
        set @ChangeType = 'DELETE'    
    end

    begin try

        begin tran

            if exists(select top 1 1 from deleted) --Either a DELETE or an UPDATE
            begin               
                --Insert into other table...        
            end

            if exists(select top 1 1 from inserted) --Either an INSERT or an UPDATE
            begin               
                --Insert into other table...    
            end 

        commit tran

    end try

    begin catch
        if xact_state() <> 0 rollback tran
        print(error_message())
    end catch

END
```

Comment: What are the constraints that stop you merging the 2 triggers?

Comment: FYI `exists(select top 1 1 from deleted)` can be simplified to `exists (select 1 from deleted)`

Comment: Does [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-nested-triggers-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16) help?

Comment: @DaleK Trigger 1 is being added to our tables right now via a dynamic SQL script. Trigger 2 is only for 1 specific table for now, but there might be others later. I'd rather keep things clean and modular from the get-go.

Comment: @DaleK for your tip - the `top 1` is there because there might be multiple rows in the deleted table. I only need to check to see if 1 row exists, nothing more.

Comment: Exists doesn't care how many rows, it will stop as soon as it finds one. Under the hood that gets removed. And to my mind its confusing as a user, you're not trying to detect that only 1 rows exists, you're trying to detect if any row exists.

Comment: @TheMortiestMorty Dale is correct *exists* will terminate as soon as it evaluates to true, the `top` operator is redundant.

Comment: Having triggers is terrible for performance. Having multiple triggers is double terrible. If you only have a single trigger at least its only a single context. So every new trigger you add is a killer for performance.

Comment: However I also have done what you are doing in the past, and you have 2 approaches 1) If the trigger updates columns that no user would update or vice versa, you can detect that column update using the `update` trigger function, and bail early. The second approach is you can order your triggers to ensure 1 runs before the other, then you can set a context value in the first trigger and if its set bail  early in the second.

Comment: And for another tip you can write `set nocount, xact_abort on` as a single statement.

Comment: Ok that's fair. I didn't know exists works like that. For the trigger stuff though, every table will have a trigger to automagically update the "automatic" columns whenever any other normal column is updated. We want this for all our tables. The other trigger is because we want to keep an audit trail of any changes done to one of our most important tables because things are randomly getting changed and we need to see when they were changed and who did it.

Comment: @DaleK how do you order triggers and set a context value?

Comment: Um you search for those terms and do some research and then ask when stuck?

Comment: @DaleK I did, but I don't see the solution. Even if I set T1 to fire first then T2 using `sp_settriggerorder`, how do I pass a variable between them?

Comment: You can use the TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL function to see if the trigger execution is nested and perform some action. It can both check if you nest your own call or nest from some other trigger. Btw, your trigger code is well, NOT great. I would recommend creating specific insert/delete/update triggers instead of those checks. As a side-note, i believe the trigger execution order is left unspecified and cannot be controlled. Also, your try catch looks pointless, better just to propagate the error.

Comment: @TheMortiestMorty well you didn't answer as to whether there are columns that are only updated by either the first trigger or the user, because that is your easiest approach.

Comment: If you have up to 3 triggers you can control the order; The link I posted earlier explains controlling nested triggers...

Comment: @siggemannen not true you can specify trigger order, or at least run first or run last (I forget now). I wouldn't recommend it, because it makes things fragile, but its possible.

Comment: Hmm, strange, i remember it was discoraged before, but maybe it was a local thing. Anyway, i still think it's a bad idea, and fragile as well

Comment: Personally I would avoid *all* of this and just ensure that the inserts/updates happen via procedures where the correct data can be inserted in the first place. Other notes: Do NOT rollback manually in a trigger, instead use `THROW` to throw an error, which causes an immediate rollback. There is no need to `CATCH` and rollback, it happens anyway if `XACT_ABORT` is on.  Your other trigger has an issue: if you are doing a joined update then give every table reference an alias, then on the first line do `UPDATE someAlias` rather than `UPDATE realTableName` or you could get an unintended crossjoin